# Why does this not produce an error?

Tags: c

I'm confused as to why this does not cause an error.

```
void f(int I) { 
  ++I;
  if (I > INT_MAX) {
    printf("OVERFLOW\n");
  } else {
    printf("NO OVERFLOW\n");
  }
}

int main(void) {
  f(INT_MAX);
  printf("DONE\n");
}
```

I'm coding in C, and my school defined INT_MAX for us already to be $2^{31} - 1$ I think is what it is.

Comment: What error are you expecting?  That the compiler didn't complain about undefined behavior when overflowing a signed `int`?  That `I > INT_MAX` can never be true?

Comment: Yeah, like, something like I is an int and since it has too big of a value, an error occurs

Comment: You need to do `if(i == INT_MAX) { /* overflow */ } else i++`.

Answer (score 1):

This can give you NO OVERFLOW on two different routes:

1. Your compiler has the right to optimize out your if statement. Since nothing of int type can be >INT_MAX, it's always false, thus your `if` is compiled to a simple `printf("NO OVERFLOW\n");`.
2. For the other one you need to know 2-complement. If you add 1 to INT_MAX, it turns around, and becomes the smallest number an int can represent. So `2147483647+1=-2147483648`, which doesn't make sense in maths, but here it's a design feature. This makes adding reasonably large negative numbers to positive numbers work well. Just you need to keep in mind to use the proper type to hold your numbers.

(I'm assuming a "normal" 32 bit int, but some architectures use different size, e.g. on AVR8 ints are 16 bit long.)

Comment: If you add 1 to `INT_MAX`, in principle you get undefined behavior.  In practice, you're likely to wrap around to `INT_MIN`, but better to not depend on that.

Comment: [C11 Standard - 3.4.3 overflow (definition)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3p3) *"An example of undefined behavior is the behavior on integer overflow."*

Answer (score 1):

`OVERFLOW` will not be printed in your case. What is happening in your case is that: When your `I` is already at the maximum, and if you further increase it using `++I`, it will wrap around to the lowest value. Illustration:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void f(int I) {
  ++I;
  printf("\nAfter incrementing I: %d\n", I);
  if (I > INT_MAX) {
    printf("OVERFLOW\n");
  } else {
    printf("NO OVERFLOW\n");
  }
}

int main(void) {
  f(INT_MAX);
  printf("DONE\n");
}
```

Output:

```
After incrementing I: -2147483648
NO OVERFLOW
DONE
```

Comment: Not really proof — illustration, perhaps.  It is undefined behaviour.  What you show is one common form of undefined behaviour, but there are many other possibilities that would also be valid.